# In probability do the term "intersection" and sign $\cap$ have multiple meanings?

Tags: probability

I'm reading articles such as [this one](https://stattrek.com/probability/probability-rules.aspx#:%7E:text=The%20probability%20of%20the%20intersection%20of%20Events%20A%20and%20B,union%20of%20A%20and%20B.) about rules of probability. I feel that the concept "intersection" and sign ∩ are not used exactly the same in different places.

Usage 1:

> The probability that Events A and B both occur is the probability of the intersection of A and B. The probability of the intersection of Events A and B is denoted by P(A ∩ B). If Events A and B are mutually exclusive, P(A ∩ B) = 0.

So if the Experiment is tossing a coin, Event A occurs when result is head, Event B occurs when result is tail. A and B are mutually exclusive and P(A ∩ B) = 0.

Usage 2:

> Rule of Multiplication The probability that Events A and B both occur is equal to the probability that Event A occurs times the probability that Event B occurs, given that A has occurred.
>
> P(A ∩ B) = P(A) P(B|A)

So again if Event A occurs when result is head and Event B occurs when result is tail, P(A ∩ B) = P(A) P(B|A) = 0.5 * 0.5 = 0.25

I found the usage of the term "intersection" and the sign ambiguous and confusing.

I do understand that somehow the Experiment in the second usage has changed from "tossing a coin" to "tossing a coin two times", and sample space changed from {head, tail} to {head-head, head-tail, tail-head, tail-tail}. So it seems to me the differences are

In usage 1, the term "intersection" and the sign means the intersection of the events in the same sample space, i.e. the overlapping of the two Events.

In usage 2, the term means the Event where A & B occur in sequence in a Double Experiment of two consecutive tossing (the single Experiment).

I was assuming mathmatic terms and signs should have very clear and definite meanings. Did I miss something?

Thanks

Bing

Comment: The multiplication rule is still valid for the first one, it's just that $P(B | A) = 0$ if $B$ and $A$ are disjoint events. For a single coin flip, the conditional probability that I flip heads, given that I flipped tails, is zero.

Comment: Aha, thanks for pointing this out. Now it makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, in every case the intersection is literally set-theoretic intersection.

So in your experiment the state space (the set of all possible outcomes) is $\Omega = \{H, T\}$.  The event $A$ is the subset $A := \{H\} \subset \Omega$ and the event $B$ is the subset $B = \{T\} \subset \Omega$.  The intersection $A \cap B$ is the empty set, because no possible outcome is in both $A$ and $B$, so we have

$$P(A \cap B) = P(\emptyset) = 0$$

Now $P(B | A)$, by definition, is $P(B \cap A) / P(A)$.  Since $P(B \cap A)$ is zero, so is $P(B | A)$.  In this situation $P(B | A)$ means "the probability that the coin came up tails, given that we know it came up heads," so it shouldn't be surprising that the probability is zero.

> I do understand that somehow the Experiment in the second usage has changed from "tossing a coin" to "tossing a coin two times", and sample space changed from {head, tail} to {head-head, head-tail, tail-head, tail-tail}.

No, you've misinterpreted something here.  Both rules apply all the time; there's no need to change to a different experiment to apply the second one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I now realised how I got confused. In my "usage 1" calculation, A denotes head B debotes tail. P(B∩A)=0. In "usage 2", A actually denotes a first toss being a head, B denotes the second toss being a tail. P(B∩A) meaning probability that two tosses being head followed by tail, being 0.25. Now I understands the rule of multiplication applies the same in both case thanks to Rivers McForge's comment and your answer. I got confused because I unconsciously changed the definition of the events and resulted P(B∩A) differently. Thanks again!